# Why can't we use the Neyman-Pearson likelihood ratio directly?

Tags: experimental-physics, probability, statistics, error-analysis, signal-processing

If you have a bunch of events and would like to choose a cut to distinguish background and signal, you can take the likelihood ratio

$$
\lambda(\vec x) = \frac{f(\vec x| s)}{f(\vec x| b)}
$$

and the Neyman-Pearson lemma says: if you choose your cuts such that $\lambda(\vec x) > c$ inside the acceptance region $A$ and $\lambda(\vec x) < c$ everywhere outside, then this choice of A gives the highest signal efficiency for a given background efficiency (determined by $c$).

Here, our event variables are $x_i$, and they are distributed according to $f(x_i|s)$ and $f(x_i|b)$ for signal and background samples. A whole event is given by $\vec x$, with PDFs $f(\vec x|s)$ and $f(\vec x|b)$.

Now, it is sometimes said that one often can't use the Neyman-Pearson lemma directly, because the PDFs are not known directly (at least not analytically). What I don't understand is, in a typical HEP analysis we do have the PDFs - namely the background and signal histograms. $f(x_i|b$) is just the normalized histogram of $x_i$ for the background. **Why can't we just take the $\boldsymbol n$-dimensional histograms for signal and BG, divide them, choose a cutoff $\boldsymbol c$ of our liking, and call it a day?**

Now that I write this, I realize two possible reasons:

- Is it simply that the $n$ dimensional histogram gets too sparse too quickly, and we would need too many events to fill it properly? A multivariate analysis can deal with >10 variables, but I can't fully fill a 10-dimensional histogram...

  - Would it work for say <= 4 dimensions?
  - One could try to fit an $n$-dimensional function to the events, maybe a few variables at a time. I have no idea if this is feasible at all. Does anybody do this?
- It might be a problem that the boundary $A$ has a complicated, jagged shape in this case.

(I *guess* I answered it myself, but it would be great if someone could corroborate that this is indeed the reason that it doesn't work in practice.)